# Left outer join has different results in two different SQL Server versions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, outer-join

I have a table named `Table1` with two integer fields:

```
ID1  ID2
1    NULL
2    NULL
3    1
```

I have a view of this table named `ViewOfTable1`:

```
SELECT ID1, ID2, 'Ok' AS Flag
FROM Table1
WHERE ID2 IS NOT NULL
```

I run the following query:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, ViewOfTable1.Flag
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN ViewOfTable1 ON Table1.ID = ViewOfTable1.ID2
```

I expect the result to be :

```
ID    Flag
1     Ok
2     NULL
3     NULL
```

And this is what I get on my machine with SQL Server Desktop Edition installed, but when I run this query in another machine with SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Edition SP4 I get:

```
ID    Flag
1     Ok
2     OK
3     OK
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Double check that the data is the same.

Comment: Where did 'ID3' come from? There is no mention in your code of a column being renamed to this. This looks either your data is different (like @Namphibian said) or your queries/view are/is different.

Comment: I can send you images of the different results

Comment: I tested this on another machine and there are 'Ok's returned for all rows...

Comment: Check your view definition is the same. Select * from view on both servers and compare results.

Comment: I double checked my work and found nothing different but the main problem is why 'Ok' is returned in all rows. there is just one row in the View but 3 'Ok's are returned

Comment: What SP is the machine running DE on?

Comment: Do you still have that problem or did you solve it?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the view definition is the same in both instances?

Comment: It could be a bug though that has been fixed in recent version. Version 2000, well, is out of support I think: http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=PN&alpha=SQL

Comment: This bug seems similar: [Incorrect query results with Enterprise edition indexed view substitution and NULL usage.](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/471201/incorrect-query-results-with-enterprise-edition-indexed-view-substitution-and-null-usage)